# Remote Validation in asp.net mvc 3 Not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I am trying to implement remote validation by following tutorial from [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) but it is not working in my case My code as follows
Web.Conf

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-AutoStart" value="true" />
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Sleep" value="60000" />
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Age" value="120000" />
  </appSettings>
```

Site.Master

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")%>"></script>
```

View

```
<div class="editor-field">
     <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CNIC)%>
      <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CNIC)%>
</div>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult CheckDuplicate(string myvar)
        {
            return Json(!myvar.Equals("362-662-1"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Model

```
[Remote("CheckDuplicate", "Home", "Already Exists")]
```

In firebug i get the following output which is different from exptected

```
 <input type="text" value="" name="uname" id="uname" data-val-required="This Field is Required" data-val="true">
while tutorial shows the following for its textbox
<input type="text" value="" name="UserName" id="UserName" data-val-required="The UserName field is required." data-val-remote-url="/Validation/IsUID_Available" data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.UserName" data-val-remote="&amp;#39;UserName&amp;#39; is invalid." data-val-regex-pattern="(\S)+" data-val-regex="White space is not allowed" data-val-length-min="3" data-val-length-max="6" data-val-length="The field UserName must be a string with a minimum length of 3 and a maximum length of 6." data-val="true" class="text-box single-line">
```

Comment: Similar question is another page:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/37366502/4146766

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute should look like this:

```
[Remote("CheckDuplicate", "Home", ErrorMessage = "Already Exists")]
```

If you use the constructor with 3 string arguments they correspond to action, controller and area.

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Remote("CheckDuplicate", "Home", ErrorMessage = "Already Exists")]
    public string CNIC { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult CheckDuplicate(string cnic)
    {
        return Json(!cnic.Equals("362-662-1"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<AppName.Models.MyViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")%>"></script>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CNIC)%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CNIC)%>    
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>

</asp:Content>
```

Also notice the name of the action argument passed to `CheckDuplicate` action: it should match the name of the model property.

Comment: i ve converted my app from mvc 2 to mvc 3 can this be causing some problem ??

Comment: @Tassadaque, did you perform the changes I suggested in my answer?

Comment: i see only one change "ErrorMessage = " that i made but no luck!

Comment: @Tassadaque, are you sure that you properly migrated to MVC 3? Maybe there are still references to the old System.Web.Mvc assembly? Verify that in web.config in the `<assemblies>` section you have the proper version of this assembly.

Comment: Oh! As i upgraded my app from mvc 2 long time ago we write our own remote validation attribute with the same name so that was causing all the  trouble Thanks for your help

Comment: +1 for noting that parameters passed to controller must match model properties. Solved my problem, thanks.