# MVC5 ViewModel Validation Remote

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to validate a username during the same stage as validating the view model, the rest of the validation works fine however I'm trying to use the following snippet to check if a username is already in use or not:

```
// Cut down code to keep it simple.
public class UserAccountRegistration
{
    [Remote("CheckUsername", "Validation", ErrorMessage = "Username already exists.")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

I have a controller named "ValidationController.cs" within the Controllers directory, that controller contains the following:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Test.Helpers;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace Test.Controllers
{
    public class ValidationController : Controller
    {
    // GET: Validation
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult CheckUsername(string Username)
    {
        Encryption hlpEncryption = new Encryption();
        DataConnections hlpDBConn = new DataConnections();

        bool bUsernameAlreadyExists = false;
        string sEncUsername = hlpEncryption.Encrypt(p_sUsername);

        SqlConnection conn = hlpDBConn.DBConnection();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CheckIfUsernameExists", conn) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", sEncUsername);

            conn.Open();
            bUsernameAlreadyExists = (Convert.ToInt16(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) > 0);
            conn.Close();
        }

        return Json(bUsernameAlreadyExists, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

}

However it the `CheckUsername` method doesn't even get hit, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's double check a couple of things:

You have correctly referenced the following libraries in the layout (preferably) and in this order:

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

On your web config file you have:

```
  <appSettings>    
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

On your view something like:

```
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Username)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Username)
```

More important the Remove validation doesn't fire until you click submit the first time. You need to include the previous text inside a < form> with a submit button to be able to validate the Username. It's not automatically as Regex, Required or StringLength. I think this works that way to avoid request the server until the user is sure that's the Username he wants.

Comment: Hi, okay going through it seems that I do have everything you have mentioned, however in my _Layout.cshtml file I have the following lines:   

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

Comment: @MrDKOz You can put the links directly or use bundles like you have. Just confirm that the bundle bundles/jquery on App_Start/BundleConfig.cs is including the three you need: jquery, jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive. If you check the source code of the page in the browser it needs to include the three scripts.

Comment: Sorted. Thank you so much! In the end it was the bundle that was missing these references.

Answer (score 1):

The property name on the model and the parameter of the CheckUsername function need to be equal. I think they are not case sensitive.
Try with:

```
    public JsonResult CheckUsername(string Username)
    {
    //change p_sUsername for Username
    //...
    }
```

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks for the reply! I've tried changed the parameter name (also changed in the above code) and it's still not even hitting the CheckUsername function - confirmed this by placing a breakpoint inside the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

jquery, jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive scripts must be referenced in your view, and also the html **name** attribute of the username field in your view must match the input of the CheckUsername method, so this will work.

```
<input type="text" name="p_sUsername" />
```

but this may cause model binding issues since your property is `public string Username { get; set; }`, so the best practice is to keep all of them the same.